# Проблема с созданием таблицы с Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть класс DTO:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserDTO implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    @Email
    protected String email;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Username can't be empty")
    @Min(3)
    protected String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Password can't be empty")
    @Min(8)
    protected String password;

    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[7-8]{10})")
    @NotNull(message = "Phone number can't be empty")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String phoneNumber;

    @Pattern(regexp = "/^[а-я ,.'-]+$/i")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String firstName;

    @Pattern(regexp = "/^[а-я ,.'-]+$/i")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String secondName;

    @Pattern(regexp = "/^[а-я ,.'-]+$/i")
    protected String patronimicName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "City can't be empty")
    @Min(3)
    protected String city;
}
```

Есть репозиторий:

```java
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<UserDTO, Long> {

    Optional<UserDTO> findById(Long id);

    Optional<UserDTO> findByUsername(String username);

    Optional<UserDTO> findByEmail(String email);

    Optional<UserDTO> findBySecondName(String secondName);

    Optional<UserDTO> findByFirstNameAndSecondName(String firstName, String secondName);
}
```

Но при запуске вылетает следующее:

```sql
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table users 
(id int8 not null, city varchar(255) not null check (city>=3), email varchar(255), first_name 
varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null check (password>=8), patronimic_name 
varchar(255), phone_number varchar(255) not null, second_name varchar(255) not null, username 
varchar(255) not null check (username>=3), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
```

И в конце якобы подсказка:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: оператор не существует: character varying >= integer
  Подсказка: Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
  Позиция: 77
```

Comment: Что значит строка больше 3? И DTO объекты не предназначены для работы с репозиторием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете аннотацию `@Min(3)` над атрибутом с типом `String`, например над атрибутом `protected String city;` , однако для проверки на длину строки необходимо использовать `@Length(min=, max=)`